# Wordpress customize.php blank page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a quite stupid problem with my wordpress. 
I've installed additional theme which I bought. Some time later I changed something in settings (website URL) www.domain.com on www.domain.com/start - there were some problems, but I changed row in database to previous settings and everything worked fine, except customize.php... When I enter it now - only appears blank page... I tried to change debug mode ON - it doesn't help because not returning any error. I made deactivation all of my plugins - nothing. Updating all files to wp-admin from clear install - changes nothing. 
I noticed, that when I setting as active one of default themes - customize.php works fine and everything is loaded, problem is only with my payware theme. 
What else... I catched in chroome, some error when I clicked on customize:

```
GET https://www.finlab.pl/wp-admin/customize.php?theme=caps 500 (Internal Server Error) load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,farbtastic,jquery-ui-core,jquery-u…:3
```

Maybe it's ajax problem ? I don't have any idea how to fix it now and where I need to look for solution. 
Please, help me...

Comment: 500 response code actually suggests that it is somekind of PHP error but problem is that you are not seeing any error messages. This is example of how php.ini settings should be when you are debugging your application (display_errors and error_reporting are most important ones): https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-development There is not much anyone can do about it without finding out actual error messages.

Answer (score 0):

**On HOMEPAGE, do you redirection**?

If so, see the solution: [https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31641](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31641#comment:1)